# ReactJS - How do you set the state of a component from a different component?

Tags: reactjs

```
MainComponent
    ComponentA
    ComponentB
```

MainComponent contains ComponentA and ComponentB. When ComponentB changes state, I'd like to get the value of what changed and pass that into ComponentA, then change the state of ComponentA to have that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a reason to switch to redux/flux, your problem can be easily solved by maintaining the state in `MainComponent`. Actually, having your child components `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` maintain their own state it's agains React best practices.

Try to keep as many of your components as possible stateless, and have a stateful component above them in the hierarchy that passes its state to its children via `props`. For your example, `MainComponent` should be a stateful component that manages the state of all child components (`ComponentA` and `ComponentB`)

You can find more information about that in [react documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-components-should-have-state)

Comment: You're right. I was actually able to get it to work with what you said. Can you explain when you'd want to use redux then? I'm rather confused. Also thank you for informing me about the best practices.

Comment: You want to use Redux (or Flux) to centralize the state of your application, or in other words, it helps you work with states in a easier way as your app keeps growing.

Comment: You can get all information you need about Redux from their official documentation: http://redux.js.org/.

P.S. Redux is hard to initially grasp and you'll need it once you feel that you have to many states to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Either you maintain the state of `ComponentB` in `MainComponent` and talk through callbacks, or use `redux` to do your state management. Unfortunately, `react` is not a state management tool so it can be tedious to do the task you're asking.

Comment: I'm a beginner and was wondering why this felt so awkward. Now I understand that this is the time to redux! Thanks, I'll learn!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to Do is use a library like Redux which use a common place to store all states and you will be able to access data easily through that.